# DbContext.ChangeTracker, DbContext.Entry() inconsistencies

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, change-tracking

Under the debugger I have a case where `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entry(e)` returns an entry with a `State` of `Detached`. When I enumerate the results of `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()` and the entries of the underlying `ObjectContext` when looking for `e`, I find an entry with a `State` of `Unchanged` (expected).

What is going on?

Here are some additional details:

- using POCO entities.
- change Tracking is on
- proxy creation is off
- lazy loading is off
- problem does not occur when saving an entity for the first time (e.g. adding to context); occurs when getting old entity into context then trying to make changes to it. This is an aggregate root with many "reference" entities that aren't supposed to change
- `Equals` is overridden on the entities and `IEquatable<T>` is implemented. That code is generated by T4.
- I am using a generic repository implementation that is declaratively configured to generate rules for saving (e.g. whether entities should be added, attached/modified, attached/unchanged. It seems to be doing this in the right order. For example the aggregate root is added/attached last because attaching it first brings in other entities in a modified state (adding those first as unchanged prevents this).

Comment: Did you call `DetectChanges`?

Comment: @SLaks - No. Is this perhaps something I have to do?

Comment: Provide more details about your situation (what have you done to get this inconsistency). Also make sure that e is same instance as in `ChangeTracker` and that you didn't override `Equals` method on the entity.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - I'll add to the details. I have solved the problem, but I don't know how, so it's worth updating the question since I don't know the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I have "solved" the problem, but I still want to know what's going on, because my solution doesn't do anything to address the root cause. My "solution" looks for an entity in the change tracker (I have also looked via the `context.Entry()` and `context.Set().Local` -- when I do it with this code (I did it as a loop instead of LINQ so I could set breakpoints), it works:

```
private DbEntityEntry GetChangeTrackedEntry(IEntity mine, Type type)
    {
        foreach (var en in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (en.Entity.GetType() != type)
                continue;
            if (((IEntity)en.Entity).Id != mine.Id)
                continue;
            return en;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

> When I attempt to lookup an entity (via change tracker, the set, etc.) via using mine directly, that's when I end up with a detached case.
>
> I thought perhaps there were cases of EF using `ReferenceEquals` but @Ladislav's comment may indicate something wrong with `Equals` implementation.

If anyone has a further explanation they can edit that into this community wiki answer.